# MITM Proxy - intercept & Modify https content through python script

Tags: python, https, proxy, mitmproxy

I'm trying to intercept and modify `https` content using `Mitm Proxy`.

It works really well using the GUI but I'd like to use a `python` script.

I tried this script:

```
from mitmproxy import http


def request(flow: http.HTTPFlow) -> None:
    if flow.request.pretty_url == "https://www.facebook.com/?l":
        flow.response = http.HTTPResponse.make(
            200,  # (optional) status code
            b"Hello World, this is a test",  # (optional) content
            {"Content-Type": "text/html"}  # (optional) headers
        )

def response(flow: http.HTTPFlow):

    if flow.response.raw_content and flow.request.pretty_url == "https://www.facebook.com/?lol":
        file = open(b"C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\mitmProx\data.txt", "a")
        file.write(str(flow.response.) + "\n")
```

However, the content I intercept is encrypted and not in clear despite the fact that the content is clear on the web GUI !

Does anyone have an idea why my script intercepts encrypted content and the web GUI prints the clear data?

Comment: Can you give an example of a resource how it is shown in GUI and how it is saved in data.txt?

Comment: Yes, here are some screenshots: https://ibb.co/ncYZPyZ & https://ibb.co/3rSwdn9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use `response.text` or `response.content`, not `response.raw_content`. raw_content contains the raw *compressed* HTTP message body, whereas `.content` contains the uncompressed version.

Comment: Exactly ! This is so obvious now.. thanks for your answer !